# ActionBar With Spinner (NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

In my app, I need an ActionBar with a dropdown on it (a spinner / setNavigationMode NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST). The ActionBar needs to be visible in all the views/screens of the app, but the content underneath it changes - it's a list of items that when clicked, a detailed view of the item is seen.

The ActionBar state should be persistent throught the different views (e.g. the selected item in the drop down).

What would be the correct way to do it? I can think of:

1. A base activity that initializes the ActionBar by calling `actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST)`, attaching an adapter if needed etc. (How to persist the dropdown state?)
2. Using fragments
3. Another way?

Which of these ways is preferred?

Thanks

Comment: Note that `NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST` is deprecated in the L Developer Preview and should remain deprecated in the next production release of Android. Custom navigation is still supported, IIRC, so you might consider using your own `Spinner`. With respect to your general question, I suspect that using fragments, and swapping the fragment based on the `Spinner`, will meet your UI request the best.